# Is there any way to identify whether the current browser is JxBrowser

Tags: javascript, jxbrowser

I am using JxBrowser and there is some sort of logic in my application which I want to avoid if the browser is JxBrowser. I am using *navigator.userAgent* in my javascript which does not contain JxBrowser in the list but shows *chrome* for JxBrowser as it is based on *chromium*. Hoping there is some api which can identify JxBrowser.

Comment: Ask JxBrowser developers if they can build next version browser with some uniq string which can identify JxBrowser via User-agent string. I believe that it will not be problem. Or ask them and they will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@step Thanks pointing into right direction, I have managed to find that JxBrowser already have the feature to include a user agent
https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013113-user-agent

Answer (score 0):

**How about this?**

```
<script>

   currentBrowser=navigator.appCodeName;
   alert(currentBrowser);

</script>
```

Comment: @M Hasan Nudin, using above script, it always give appCode as 'Mozzilla'